# Decomposition of continuous functionals on $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Consider a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and a continuous linear functional $\varphi:A\to\mathbb{C}$ with adjoint given by $\varphi^*(a):=\overline{\varphi(a^*)}$. We know that each positive (cont. lin.) functional is self-adjoint.

How would one show that each $\varphi\in A^*$ can be written as a linear combination of two self-adjoint members of $A^*$?

**My attempt:**

I thought I'd try with $\varphi_1(a+ib):=\varphi(a)$ and $\varphi_2(a+ib):=\varphi(b)$, though I am unsure whether $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ are indeed self-adjoint. I manage to conclude that $\varphi_1^*(a+ib)=\overline{\varphi(a)}$ and $\varphi_1^*(a+ib)=\overline{\varphi(b)}$, but am unsure if concluding those equal to $\varphi(a),\varphi(b)$ would be legal. Note that both $a$ and $b$ are self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\varphi^{**}(a)=\overline{\varphi^*(a^*)}&=\overline{\overline{\varphi(a^{**})}}=\varphi(a)\\
(\varphi+\psi)^*(a)=\overline{(\varphi+\psi)(a^*)}&=
\overline{\varphi(a^*)+\psi(a^*)}=\overline{\varphi(a^*)}+\overline{\psi(a^*)}
=\varphi^*(a)+\psi^*(a)\\
(\lambda \varphi)^*(a)=\overline{\lambda\varphi(a^*)}&=
\bar{\lambda}\overline{\varphi(a^*)}=\bar{\lambda}\varphi^*(a)
\end{align}
$$
Any time you have a vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{C}$ with a complex linear involution $i\colon V\to V$ with the properties
$$
\begin{align}
i(i(v))&=v\\
i(v+w)&=i(v)+i(w)\\
i(\lambda v)&=\bar\lambda i(v)
\end{align}
$$
the self-adjoint elements are $v\in V$ such that $i(v)=v$ and any $v\in V$ has a decomposition $v=\Re(v)+\sqrt{-1}\Im(v)$ where
$$
\begin{split}
\Re(v)=\frac{v+i(v)}{2}\\
\Im(v)=\frac{v-i(v)}{2\sqrt{-1}}
\end{split}
$$
and $\Re(v),\Im(v)$ are self-adjoint.